# duplicated indexes in sql server

Tags: sql-server

This is a case:
I wanna make sure of the thing I'm going to do is right or wrong.
The case:

- lets say I have two tables on sql server with different names of two of them. and I have created an index for two of the tables with the same indexes names but I typed in every index query or script (use table name) and I specified the table name in the script.
- the question, would I get conflict values in the indexes if I run the script or the index triggered?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are using here. An `INDEX` name only needs be unique for the object it is defined against. If you had 2 tables, `dbo.T` and `dbo.I`, *both* could have an `INDEX` named `IX_ID`. These would be 2 separate objects and wouldn't conflict. This *isn't* the same for `CONSTRAINTS`, however, so (for example) if you create a `PRIMARY KEY` `CONSTRAINT` on both called `PK_ID` then the creation of the second `CONSTRAINT` would fail, as an object of the same name already exists within the same database and schema.

Comment: You need to show us what you mean because your question is unclear

Comment: your examples are perfect and got the answer that I was looking for. Thanks Larnu